# How to reproduce this format in latex or tikz

Tags: formatting, tikz-styles, bold, addlines

I was wondering whether is possible to reproduce the following image in latex or tikz.
[image]
[image]

Hopefully is easy!

Poor try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Name} \underline{SDASDASDASDSADASD   \hspace{8cm}  } \\
    \textbf{Signature} \underline{SADASDASD \hspace{10cm}}\\
    \\
    \\
    \\


\textbf{Name}  \hspace{8cm} \textbf{Name}  \\\\
\\
\\
 \underline{\hspace{5cm}} \hspace{3cm} \underline{\hspace{5cm}}

\end{document}
```

---

I learned this by reading this forum:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2,>=latex,block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em}]
 \node[circle, draw, minimum width=2] (A) {$RE$};
 \node[circle, draw,  minimum width=5em, right = 0.2 of A] (B) {$Gen$}; 
 \node[circle, above right =of B] (C) {$LT$}; 
 \node[circle, below right =of B] (D) {$V_t$};
 \node[circle, below = 0 of D] (E) {$P_t$};
 \node[circle, below =0 of E] (F) {$Q_t$};
 \node[circle, right = 5.5 of B] (G) {};
 \node[circle, above = 3 of G] (H) {HT};
 \node[circle, minimum width=2em,  below = 0.5 of G] (J) {};
 \node[rectangle,line width=1mm, draw, minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em, below right = 1.5  and 0.5 of G] (I) {};
 \node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, above = 1.25 of G] (K) {};
 \node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, right = 4 of K] (L) {};
 \node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, above = 1.65 of L] (M) {}; 
 \node[circle, inner sep=0pt, above right = 1.4 and 0.1 of L] (N) {}; 

 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (B) -- (A);
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (C) -- (D);
 \draw[->] (E.0) -- ++ (0.6,0);
 \draw[->] (F.0) -- ++ (0.6,0);
 \draw[-] (B.0) -- ++ (2.8,0) arc (180:-180:4.5mm) ++ (0.6,0) arc (180:-180:4.5mm) ++ (0.9,0) -| (G.90) node[pos=-0.25,above=0.5]{Transformer}  ;
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (G.270) -- (H);
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (G.90) -- (J.270) ;
 \draw[-, line width=1.5mm] (J.90) -| (I.90) ;
 \draw[->, line width=1.5mm] (I.270) -- ++ (0,-0.1) .. controls +(0,-0.1) and +(0,0.1) .. ++ (-.3,-.3) .. controls +(0,-0.05) and +(-0.2,-0) .. ++ (.35,0) .. controls +(.8,-0) and +(-0,0) .. ++ (-.4,-.6)  ;
 \draw[-] (K) -- ++ (1,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=0.8,segment amplitude=5pt,segment length=6pt] -- ++ (2,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=10] -- (L) node[pos=-0.95,below=0.2]{\scriptsize Transformation Line 1} ;
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (G.270) -- (H);
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (L) -- (M.90);
 \draw[-, line width=1mm] (L.90) -- ++ (0,-4.6);
 \draw[snake=border,segment angle=140,segment length=5pt, segment amplitude=10pt] (N) -- ++(0,-6.2) node[text width=1cm,align=center,pos=0.5,right =0.2]{Infinite bus} node[text width=1cm,align=center,pos=.95,right =-0.1]{$V_a$};
 \draw[-] (L) |- ++ (-.2,-3.3);

 %\draw[-] (0,3) -- ++ (1,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=0.8,segment amplitude=5pt,segment length=6pt] %-- ++ (2,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=10] -- (4,3) node[pos=-0.95,below=0.2]{\scriptsize %Transformation Line 1} ;

 %\draw[-] (4,5) -- ++ (-1,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=0.8,segment amplitude=5pt,segment %length=6pt] -- ++ (-2,0) [snake=coil,segment aspect=10] -- (0,5) %node[pos=-0.95,below=0.2]{\scriptsize Transformation Line 1} ;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To answer your question in a simple way: it surely is possible! But: what did you try so far?

Comment: Currently, trying to figure it out and... I failed. I don't know how to do the big bold line at the top neither the double lines. I'll update my post. Also, I would like to add another code that has nothing to do with my question, just to show that I can use latex or tikz after watching some examples.

Comment: Check out the Diamond arrow head (page 214).  While there is no [thickness=...] option, there is a `\thickness` length (along with predefined thicknesses like thin, thick, extra thick...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this. It might not be the best way, but I hope it is helpful.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=40mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{densely dotted}=[dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 0.25pt]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex,block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em}]
 \node[diamond, inner sep=2pt] (1) {};
 \node[diamond, draw,fill=black] (3) {};
 \node[diamond, inner sep=2pt, right= 5 of 3] (2) {};
 \node[diamond, draw,fill=black, right= 5 of 1] (4) {};
 \node[diamond, inner sep=2pt, below right = 1.4 and -0.3 of 4] (5) {}; 
 \node[diamond, inner sep=2pt, below right = 1.4 and 3.6 of 4] (6) {};
 \node[diamond, below left = 1.5 and 2.8 of 1] (7) {\textbf{dasdasdsadsadas: ~~~}};  
 \node[diamond, below left = -1 and -2.1 of 7] (8) {\textbf{xzczxczxczxczxc: ~~~~~}};
 \node[diamond, below left = -1 and -2.1 of 8] (9) {\textbf{asdreqweqweqwee: ~~~}}; 
 \node[diamond, below left = 0 and -2.1 of 9] (11) {\textbf{dasdas: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}};  
 \node[diamond, below left = -0 and -1.8 of 11] (12) {\textbf{dasdasdasd}};  
 \node[diamond, right = 5 of 12] (13) {\textbf{sadasdasdasd}};          
 %
 \draw[-, line width=.86mm] (1) -- (2);
 \draw[-, line width=.5mm] (1.-60) -- node[pos=0.5, above=0.2]{\textbf{asdasdasdasdas}} (2.240);
 \draw[-, line width=.5mm] (1.60) -- node[pos=0.5,above]{} (2.120);
 \draw [double, double distance between line centers=1.7, line width=.4mm] (5) -- node[pos=0.7, above=-0.08]{\textbf{ereadadssad}} (6);
 \draw[densely dotted, line width=.5mm] (7.-05)  -- ++ (12,0) node[pos=0.13,above]{xcvbnmmnbvc};
 \draw[densely dotted, line width=.5mm] (8.-05)  -- ++ (12,0) node[pos=0.41,above]{sadasdasdasdasdsadsadasdsadadsadasddsadasdasdasdsadasd};
 \draw[densely dotted, line width=.5mm] (9.-05)  -- ++ (12,0) node[pos=0.44,above]{sadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadasdasdsasdasdasdasdasdsad}; 
 \draw[densely dotted, line width=.5mm] (-2,-6)  -- ++ (12,0) node[pos=0.5,above]{};
 \draw[densely dotted, line width=.5mm] (11.-05)  -- ++ (12,0) node[pos=0.18,above]{sadasdasdasdasdsadas};
 \draw[-, line width=.5mm] (-5.6,-11)  -- ++ (4,0) node[pos=0.36,below]{dsrfghbndrs};
 \draw[-, line width=.5mm] (2.7,-11)  -- ++ (5.2,0) node[pos=0.45,below]{sdasdasdasdasdsadd};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```